# When the declaration of the function is in a traditional style, why isn't the output correct?

Tags: c, stdout, header-files, object-code

I have declared the function `pow` in the traditional way of declaration in C. However, the output of function is incorrect. I don't need to include math.h here as I am declaring the function and the object code for it is already present. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

double pow();           //traditional declaration doesnt work, why??

int main()
{
    printf("pow(2, 3) = %g", pow(2, 3));
    return 0;
}
```

The output for the above is 1 whereas it should be 8. Please help me with it.

Comment: Hello close voter for "no MCVE". Please explain what is missing. I can see one right there in the question and it is even explained in all its weird detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> traditional declaration doesnt work, why??

Because without a prototype, those two ints you provided don't get converted to the doubles that `pow` actually accepts. With "traditional" declarations you must painstakingly make sure you provided *exactly* the type of arguments expected by the function, or you'll have yourself undefined behavior in your program.

This is one reason to favor prototypes, and to actually use the standard library headers that provide them for standard functions.

Comment: got it! Thanks a ton!

Comment: "make sure you provided exactly the type of arguments expected".  Almost.  `float tw = 2; float th = 3;  pow(tw, th)` would have worked fine.  The correct type, after the _usual promotions_, is needed.  Just like `printf()`.